Jupyter Application launch error from Anaconda Environment
I tried to launch Jupyter Lab and Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda Environment but it did not work and appear this message:
\[I 14:43:12.768 NotebookApp\] Writing notebook server cookie secret to C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\notebook_cookie_secret  
\[E 14:43:12.768 NotebookApp\] Failed to write cookie secret to C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\notebook_cookie_secret: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied: 'C:\\\\Users\\\\...\\\\AppData\\\\Roaming\\\\jupyter\\\\runtime\\\\notebook_cookie_secret'  
\[W 14:43:12.769 NotebookApp\] Could not set permissions on C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\notebook_cookie_secret  
\[W 14:43:13.159 NotebookApp\] Error loading server extension jupyter_lsp  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\notebook\\notebookapp.py", line 2050, in init_server_extensions  
func(self)  
File "C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\jupyter_lsp\\serverextension.py", line 76, in load_jupyter_server_extension  
nbapp.io_loop.call_later(0, initialize, nbapp, virtual_documents_uri)  
^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
AttributeError: 'NotebookApp' object has no attribute 'io_loop'  
\[W 14:43:14.566 NotebookApp\] Error loading server extension jupyterlab  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\notebook\\notebookapp.py", line 2050, in init_server_extensions  
func(self)  
File "C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\jupyterlab\\serverextension.py", line 71, in load_jupyter_server_extension  
extension.initialize()  
File "C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\jupyterlab\\labapp.py", line 923, in initialize  
super().initialize()  
File "C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\jupyter_server\\extension\\application.py", line 437, in initialize  
self.\_prepare_handlers()  
File "C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\jupyter_server\\extension\\application.py", line 327, in \_prepare_handlers  
self.initialize_handlers()  
File "C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\jupyterlab\\labapp.py", line 737, in initialize_handlers  
page_config\["token"\] = self.serverapp.identity_provider.token  
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
AttributeError: 'NotebookApp' object has no attribute 'identity_provider'  
\[I 14:43:14.588 NotebookApp\] Registered jupyterlab_code_formatter server extension  
\[I 14:43:14.674 NotebookApp\] \[Jupytext Server Extension\] Deriving a JupytextContentsManager from LargeFileManager  
\[C 14:43:14.822 NotebookApp\] You must use Jupyter Server v1 to load nbdime as a classic notebook server extension. You have v2.14.1 installed.  
You can fix this by executing:  
pip install -U "jupyter-server\[I 14:43:14.825 NotebookApp\] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\\Users\\...
\[I 14:43:14.825 NotebookApp\] Jupyter Notebook 6.5.7 is running at:  
\[I 14:43:14.825 NotebookApp\] http://localhost:8888/?token=ea4415adbb582389279d62b9cdeefbfbc8b63dc805c2a923  
\[I 14:43:14.825 NotebookApp\] or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=ea4415adbb582389279d62b9cdeefbfbc8b63dc805c2a923  
\[I 14:43:14.825 NotebookApp\] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).  
\[E 14:43:14.825 NotebookApp\] Failed to write server-info to C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\nbserver-4160.json: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied: 'C:\\\\Users\\\\...\\\\AppData\\\\Roaming\\\\jupyter\\\\runtime\\\\nbserver-4160.json'  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Scripts\\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 9, in  
sys.exit(main())  
^^^^^^  
File "C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\jupyter_core\\application.py", line 283, in launch_instance  
super().launch_instance(argv=argv, \*\*kwargs)  
File "C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\traitlets\\config\\application.py", line 1075, in launch_instance  
app.start()  
File "C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\notebook\\notebookapp.py", line 2358, in start  
self.write_browser_open_file()  
File "C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\notebook\\notebookapp.py", line 2261, in write_browser_open_file  
with open(self.browser_open_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:  
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
PermissionError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied: 'C:\\\\Users\\\\...\\\\AppData\\\\Roaming\\\\jupyter\\\\runtime\\\\nbserver-4160-open.html'

I tried to run Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda prompt but it also didn't work.

Are you on a work computer with limited access and/or do you have admin privileges? Have you already tried uninstalling and reinstalling jupyter in your environment?
conda update conda  
conda remove jupyter jupyterlab jupyter_core jupyter_client jupyter_server  
conda clean --all  
conda install jupyter jupyterlab


Yes I removed and reinstalled the application from Anaconda distribution, and tried again with Anaconda Prompt commands.
And I also updated all packages.
But it didn't work, could it be from the kernel?

Tyler is totally on the right track. This seems just bad approaches compounded. I'm seeing in that traceback, "Jupyter Notebook 6.5.7 is running at", which is not current. Anaconda installs Jupyter Notebook 7+ now, which means you didn't clean things out. And have in no way successfully updated. If that is there, there's no telling what else you have around. Plus, there's a note from nbdime saying it needs Jupyter Server v1, and it was updated to v2 according to here. So that seems to be another thing indicating old software in play.

Thanks, @Wayne I reinstalled Anaconda and Jupyter Notebook work from localhost but did not launch from Anaconda.

So is it solved? Not following. It should work from Anaconda if you installed the Anaconda Distribution correctly and it shouldn't list old things.  If the situation has changed, update the post and comment here that it has. I see the same error traceback as before.
